# How to show the integers have same cardinality as the natural numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How would I show the following have a bijection. Which is one to one and onto ofcourse.

$\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$

I know I need to find a function. But I do not see the pattern that makes integer go to natural. I already did this problem from natural to integer but now I want to see it done this way.

I have listed some numbers

$,..,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,..$

$1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,.$

Comment: No dont close por favor.....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I like the one that snake around, $0, -1, 1, -2, 2, -3, 3,\ldots$

So it goes

> $$\begin{cases}f: \Bbb N\to \Bbb Z \\ f(2n)=n-1 \\ f(2n-1)=-n\end{cases}$$

If you want it to go the other way, you just reverse the idea and compute the inverse of $f$.

Comment: Yes from N to Z the pattern is $n/2$ n is even, $(1-n)/2$ n is odd but I want to see from Integer to Natural. Altrough I do appreciate the insight of your pattern.

Comment: @Adam: How about letting the OP work out the inverse for themselves? It's not very difficult, and it is a good exercise.

Comment: @AsafKaragila a solid idea. I'll take that to heart.

Comment: Well you can still write it so I can compare it to mine and see if I did it correctly. If you want to ofcourse.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez you'll see we want $0\mapsto 2$, $1\mapsto 4$, et cetera so that $f^{-1}(n) = 2n+2$ when $n\ge 0$. What do you get for the negatives?

Comment: Hmm so when it is $n\ge0$ it maps to evens so I am going to guess $n<0$ it goes to odds somehow

Comment: @FernandoMartinez Yes, can you see the pattern to send negative numbers to odds now?

Comment: I think so is it $-2(n)-1$ when $n<0$

Answer (score 5):

Your list has absolutely no pattern, because you're doing it "wrong", in the sense that you are not writing it in a way that a pattern emerges.

Of course there is no *order preserving* function, so writing both sets with their natural order will promise you that there is no reasonable pattern. Instead write the natural numbers, and then try to write the integers:

$$\begin{array}
& 1 & 2&  3&  4&  5& 6&  7& 8&\ldots\\
  0 & 1& -1& 2& -2&  3& -3& 4&\ldots
\end{array}$$

This gives rise to a bijection from $\Bbb N$ onto $\Bbb Z$. Now just find its inverse.

(Note that it is in general easier to find "pattern" when $\Bbb N$ is the domain, because the list does not require you to go into two directions.)

Comment: I see it has something to do with odds and evens...

Comment: Yes, very good. What else do you see?

Answer (score 4):

By some different definitions, $\mathbb{N}$ may contain the element $0$.
So the map should look like this:

\begin{array}
  &0 & 1 & \phantom{-}2&  3&  \phantom{-}4&  5&  \phantom{-}6& 7&  \phantom{-}8&\ldots\\
   0 & 1& -1&  2& -2&  3& -3& 4& -4&\ldots
\end{array}

So the function $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{N}$ is:

$$
f(n)=\begin{cases} 2n-1 \, \text{ if } n\gt 0 \\ -2n \quad \text{ if } n \leq0\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 2):

For example
$$f:\mathbb Z\rightarrow\mathbb N$$
$$ f(n)=\begin{cases} 2n+1 \text{ if } n\geq0 \\ -2n \text{ if } n<0\end{cases}$$