# Bijection function from non-negative integers to integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What is an example of a function from the set of non-negative integers (0, 1, 2, 3..) to the set of integers? The function has to be bijective.

Comment: Odd to positive; even to negative.

Comment: Here is your answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873927/how-to-show-the-integers-have-same-cardinality-as-the-natural-numbers

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Please [thoroughly search for an answer before asking a new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  Searching for [bijection from N to Z](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=bijection+N+to+Z) gives thousands of answers.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}f:\mathbb N_0& \rightarrow \mathbb Z   \\
n &\mapsto \frac{1}{4}(1-(-1)^n(2n+1))
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$ f(n) = 
   \begin{cases} 
      n/2        & \mbox{even } n   \\
      -(n+1)/2   & \mbox{odd  } n   \\
   \end{cases} $$
$$ f^{-1}(n) = 
   \begin{cases} 
      2n        & \mbox{if } n \geq 0   \\
      -2n-1     & \mbox{if } n < 0   \\
   \end{cases}$$
$$ f: \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...\} \rightarrow \{0,-1,1,-2,2,-3,3,...\} $$
$$ f^{-1}: \{...,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,...\} \rightarrow \{...,5,3,1,0,2,4,6,...\} $$
The function $f$ is bijective